# How to save checked listview items to array in android?

Tags: android, arrays, checkbox, android-contacts, simplecursoradapter

I have an app that lists the users contacts in a listview with a checkbox using a simple cursor adapter. Upon pressing a button i would like to save the checked items to an array with a name the user has chosen using edittext so that i can display it later. Also, i was wondering how to create an array or array names or something similar allowing me to select the arrays that have been created.
Specific code is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help.

here is my code:

```
package com.contacts5;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


public class contacts5 extends ListActivity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Cursor mCursor = getContacts();
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, 


                mCursor, 

                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME ,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},


                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });


        setListAdapter(adapter);

         final ListView listView = getListView();
            listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }

    private Cursor getContacts() 
    {

        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
                + ("1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+ " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,sortOrder);
    }


    }
```

Comment: You ask for specific code, but you have posted none of your own here. What have you done so far to attempt to address your problem? Please post some code so that we can see what you are attempting to do so far.

Comment: It's not obvious what you want. Where is your onClick? you would have to write a custom Adapter